# Sencha Touch : vbox inside hbox layout issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, vbox, hbox

I am putting a vbox layout inside hbox layout. But the vbox isn't working properly. Here is the code:

Code:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen : true,
    layout : {
        type : 'hbox',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    items : [{
        width : 50,
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch'
        },
        items : [{
            flex : 1,
            html : '1st'
        }, {
            height : 50,
            html : '2nd'
        }]
    }, {
        flex : 1,
        html : 'Large'
    }]
});
```

Here, the 2 panels of vbox is coming over one another. If I just create the vbox only, it works perfectly. Here is the code:

Code:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen : true,
    layout : {
        type : 'vbox',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    items : [{
        flex : 1,
        html : '1st'
    }, {
        height : 50,
        html : '2nd'
    }]
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

EDIT:

Somehow, I find, if I swap the vbox items this way, then it works:

```
...
layout : {
     type : 'vbox',
     align : 'stretch'
},
items : [{
     height : 50,
     html : '2nd'
}, {
     flex : 1,
     html : '1st'
}]
....
```

However, I want the smaller item at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

In your hbox, the vbox itself is missing a flex or height config...

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        width: 50,
        flex:1, // this needs to be flexy as well
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            flex: 1,
            html: '1st'
        }, {
            height: 50,
            html: '2nd'
        }]
    }, {
        flex: 1,
        html: 'Large'
    }]
});
```